# Automate creation of F5 user accounts using SSH and TMSH

Tags: f5

We have a handful of F5 BIG IP devices that have to use local user accounts. We would like to have users authenticate via and SSH key which then can then use to set their account password. How can we accomplish this via SSH and Traffic Management Shell (TMSH)?

Our devices are using the following version:

```
username@(bigipwaf-vmss_0)(cfg-sync In Sync)(Active)(/Common)(tmos)# show sys version

Sys::Version
Main Package
  Product     BIG-IP
  Version     13.1.0.2
  Build       0.0.6
  Edition     Point Release 2
  Date        Tue Jan 16 08:46:28 PST 2018
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step 1: Enable [SSH public key authentication on the F5 account](https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K13454) you want to use for automation:

```
MY_KEY=$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
WAF_IP=10.0.0.100
SSH_OPTIONS=' -p 50001 ' #Optional if you need to change the SSH port or other settings
#This will prompt for the admin password twice, after which the
ssh $SSH_OPTIONS admin@$WAF 'modify auth user admin shell bash'
ssh $SSH_OPTIONS admin@$WAF "echo '$MY_KEY' | sudo tee /home/admin/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

Step 2: After the automation account is setup you can then create new local F5 accounts using:

```
Users="user1 user2 user3"
declare -A sshkeys=()

sshkeys[user1]=$(cat /home/USERNAME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) #Source from local home folder
sshkeys[user2]=$(curl -s https://github.com/torvalds.keys) #Source from public github
sshkeys[user3]=$(curl -sn "https://github-enterprise.private.com/api/v3/users/USERNAME/keys" | jq --raw-output '.[] | .key') #Setup ~/.netrc with a line like: machine github-enterprise.private.com login x-oauth-basic password INSERT_Personal_Access_Token_HERE

for SSHUser in $Users
    do
        echo -e "Adding WAF account for $SSHUser"
        ssh -p 50001 "admin@$WAF" "tmsh create auth user $SSHUser shell bash partition-access add { all-partitions { role admin } }"
        ssh -p 50001 "admin@$WAF" "sudo mkdir -p /home/$SSHUser/.ssh && echo '${sshkeys[$SSHUser]}' | sudo tee /home/$SSHUser/.ssh/authorized_keys"
        #Permissions don't seem to matter. all home files owned by root:webusers
    done
done
```

Step 3: Users can then login and set a password for their account.

```
#Login using ssh key:
ssh user1@10.0.0.100 -p 50001
#change password on account:
passwd
```

That password will then allow the user to sign into the web portal.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.